# View: Exclude nodes that have the same taxonomy term id(s) as current node

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-contextual-filters

**Drupal 8**

I have a content type with a field that holds a `Taxonomy Term Reference`. I want a View that shows other nodes of the same content type that **do not** have that field with the same **Taxonomy Term ID** as the currently viewed node.

Example:

URL: /*story/storyA*

Currently viewing a node of `Content Type Story` that has a `Taxonomy Term Reference` to **value B**. I need the view to show other stories that **do not** have that same `Taxonomy Term Reference` *to value B*.

I thought I could achieve that by

- Set up a `relationship` to the field that holds the Taxonomy Term
- Add a `Filter Criteria` of  *Term ID* associated to **above relationship** and with operator **is not equal to**. PROBLEM: how do I get the token for Value?

[image]

I also tried to go about adding a `Contextual Filter` associated to the **created relationship** and selecting `Exlude` but no dice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I was missing the adequate additional **Contextual Filter**:

- `Term ID` , `Provide default value` with `Taxonomy term ID from URL` and the options `Load default filter from node page` and `limit terms by vocab` checked. And the last bit, in `More`, I have `Exclude` checked.  This contextual filter is associated to the created relationship mentioned in the question.